# How to make div's width not change with the browser window's

Tags: html, css

There's a header div and it's width should be the same with the screen(not the window).I tried to set it's width to be 100%,
but When the browser window became narrower the div became narrower too, so when I scroll to the right, the header div isn't long enough to the right.
How to make the div width not change with the window?

Comment: You are unable to do this unless you set a fixed with. A website doesn't know the resolution of you screen only your browser. The only thing I can think of using browser detection to get you screen resolution and set that one as a fixed width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the width of the div to a fixed width.  So try

> `width:980px;`

This will prevent the div from collapsing when the browser is resized unlike setting the width with a percentage.  You may need to change the width to suite your needs or preference.

Further Reading:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Answer (score 1):

You either set it to concrete value like

```
width:1000px;
```

or with percents

```
width: 100%;
```

you can calculate width of the window on load and set it with javascript though.

Comment: Why not combine both, to get a fixed div, that will decrease on much smaller screens, like: `width: 900px; max-width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

You put `width:1000px;` in main container div. Then inner div's you put percentage or pixels.